# How to add positioning enrichment to media item in Google Photos API?

Tags: google-api, google-photos-api

Reading Google Photos API documentation on how to add position media items inside the album I can't understand what should be the request body. https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/add-enrichments#supported-positioning

I want to move `mediaItem-1` to be before `mediaItem-2` in album `album-1`. How my request body should look like?

```
POST https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/albums/album-1:addEnrichment
{
    "newEnrichmentItem": {
        enrichment-to-be-added // What goes here?
    },
    "albumPosition": {
        "position": "after-media-item",
        "relativeMediaItemId": "mediaItem-2"
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I don't want to reupload a media item to the cloud, so there will be only one version of the same media item.

Answer (score 1):

A position can only be specified when creating a media item or adding enrichments. **Existing media items in an album can't be reorganized**, so it's important to set the position of an item when it's being added.

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/add-enrichments#intro-positions

The method you are using is for Album Enrichment.

[**Enrichment Types:**](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/add-enrichments#intro-enrichment-types)

1. Text enrichments

   A text enrichment is a plain text string that can be inserted to annotate the album.
2. Location enrichments

   A location enrichment is a marker and the name of the place that can be inserted to annotate a location.
3. Map enrichments

   A map enrichment is a map with a specified origin and destination that can be inserted in the album.

Additional References:
https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/albums/addEnrichment?hl=en_US#request-body

---

**Sample media item creation with position:**
https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems/batchCreate#request-body

```
{
  "albumId": string,
  "newMediaItems": [
    {
      object (NewMediaItem)
    }
  ],
  "albumPosition": {
    object (AlbumPosition)
  }
}
```

**albumPosition**

- Position in the album where the media items are added. If not specified, the media items are added to the end of the album (as per the default value, that is, LAST_IN_ALBUM). The request fails if this field is set and the albumId is not specified. The request will also fail if you set the field and are not the owner of the shared album.

---

(UPDATE)

**Workaround:**

1. Delete mediaItem-2 in album-1
2. Create mediaItem-2 in album-1 with position parameter which will place mediaItem-2 after mediaItem-1
   https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/AlbumPosition#PositionType

---

Your request body for create media item:

```
{
  "albumId": album-1,
  "newMediaItems": [
    {
      object (mediaItem-2)
    }
  ],
  "albumPosition": {
    "position": AFTER_MEDIA_ITEM.
    "relativeMediaItemId": mediaItem-1
  }
}
```

---

Comment: Could you replace Album position and new media item with the values in my example?

Comment: the one you are looking for is for media item position (you set where to place your new media item inside your album). That can only be done when you are creating your new media item and you include the position parameters in the request body

Comment: the one you used is for adding enrichment to the album (which could also have a position parameter in the request body). It will set the position in the album where the enrichment is to be inserted. You can check the types and examples of enrichment in the link provided.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, Existing media items in an album can't be reorganized.

Comment: Is it possible to add enrichment while adding media item to another album?

Comment: sorry, that is not possible. adding a media enrichment and adding a media item uses 2 different HTTP request. Hence you need to do it separately. You can refer here to learn more about the REST Resource methods available for albums, media items and shared albums, hope this would help : https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest